# Pass by value possible in C?

Tags: c

Hello I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966570/why-declare-a-struct-that-only-contains-an-array-in-c) question, I got confused with how if we can pass arrays by value or not. Here is a piece of code which I think should pass array by value.

```
#include <cstdio>
void foo (int arr[]);
int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    foo(arr[10]);
    return 0;
}
void foo (int arr[])
{
.......
}
```

Please tell me why wouldn't it pass by value?

Thanks

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774456/pass-an-array-to-a-function-by-value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays automatically decay into pointers in certain contexts in C.  Function calls are one of those places.  That said, you are passing the *pointer* by value - C has no other way to pass parameters than "by value".

Answer (score 4):

Because this:

```
void foo(int arr[])
```

is really just syntax sugar for this:

```
void foo(int *arr)
```

So when you call the function, your array decays into a pointer to the first element.

Comment: I once coined a term for this kind of syntactic "sugar": *syntactic vinegar*.

Answer (score 1):

In short: you cannot pass an array as a function parameter and have it received as an array type by the called function.  An array expression in that context will be converted to a pointer type before it is passed to the function.

From the C language [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a
> string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is
> converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of
> the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the
> behavior is undefined.

What this means is that when you write something like

```
int arr[10];
foo(arr);
```

the expression `arr` in the call to `foo` is immediately converted to a *pointer* type; it is said to "decay" to type `int *`.  So all `foo` will ever receive is a pointer value.

More standard language:

> **6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
> *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
> elements as specified by the size expression.

What this means is that if your prototype for the function `foo` is either

```
void foo(int arr[])
```

or

```
void foo(int arr[10])
```

it will be *interpreted* as

```
void foo(int *arr)
```

Again, the definition of the language is such that you cannot pass an array expression as a function parameter and have it be received as an array type by the called function.

There are ways around this; you can wrap the array in a `struct` and pass the `struct` by value, like so:

```
struct T { int arr[10]; } var;
foo(var);
...
void foo (struct T arg) { ... }
```

As hacks go, this doesn't really buy you much.