# Is there a function to copy an array in C/C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, function, copy

I know that Java has a function `System.arraycopy();` to copy an array. I was wondering if there is a function in C or C++ to copy an array. I was only able to find implementations to copy an array by using `for` loops, pointers, etc. But is there a library function that I can use to copy an array?

Comment: `man memmove` and `man memcpy`

Comment: Don't use `memcpy`, use `std::copy`.  If your type has a meaningful copy constructor then `memcpy` will do the wrong thing.

Comment: Are you actually trying to learn C and C++ at the same time? They are very different languages.

Comment: Well I learned little bit of C and now I recently started learning C++. From what I read from an online resource, I thought C++ is just a language with a lot of additional features to C language.

Comment: @JL The two languages have evolved along different, out-of-sync paths.

Comment: @JL Consider implicit `void *` conversion, in C: `char *foo = malloc(0);` fails in C++, but works in C. VLAs are a feature added by C99 that aren't in C++. Likewise for flexible array members. Even the modulo operator isn't guaranteed to work the same in C++ as it does in C.

Comment: Also see [Why declare a struct that only contains an array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966570/why-declare-a-struct-that-only-contains-an-array-in-c)

Comment: I'm saying this because no one has mentioned it before: In C++ you should use std::vector in almost all cases. There are cases where other containers are usefull too, but i most cases std::vector will be the best option. Don't use raw arrays in C++ and try to avoid std::array unless neccessary.

Comment: Pick C or C++. They're very distinct.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Since C++11, you can copy arrays directly with [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
#include <array>
std::array<int, 4> A = {10, 20, 30, 40};
std::array<int, 4> B = A; // Copy array A into array B
```

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX: The same you would any other type that supports copy assignment. `B = A`.

Comment: I think the function is copy A's memory address to B. If I try to copy A's item values to B without changing B's  memory address. How can I do that?

Comment: @Aaron_Lee: I've just tested it, and it genuinely  copies the elements into an array in a separate memory location. The array class evidently has its own overload for the assignment operator.

Comment: You guys realize that no assignment operators appeared in those two lines of code, right? That's the copy constructor that is being called even though the notation looks like the assignment operator.

Answer (score 195):

Since you asked for a C++ solution...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

const int arr_size = 10;
some_type src[arr_size];
// ...
some_type dest[arr_size];
std::copy(std::begin(src), std::end(src), std::begin(dest));
```

Comment: erreur: ‘begin’ is not a member of ‘std’

Comment: @David天宇Wong: You're using an old compiler or you didn't include the header.  It's in `<iterator>`

Comment: Maybe you should say which includes you need.  Is copy in `<algorithm>` ?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: I could, and you could always just google "std::copy"

Comment: I only ask because if you had to explain that std::begin was in <iterator> that means people are not googling std::begin to find out what header it is in so they are unlikely to google std::copy for the same reason.  It makes a better answer if nobody has to ask stuff that is only answered in comments.  Maybe I should have just edited the answer instead of prompting you to do it.

Comment: you can change begin(src) into src and end(src) into src+arr_size

Comment: Here can be more simple like this,
`copy(src,src+n,dest);`
There, n is the array size.

Comment: @EdS.@JerryJeremiah I did not include neither `<algorithm>` nor `<iterator>` but still works. I don't know why...

Answer (score 107):

As others have mentioned, in C you would use `memcpy`. Note however that this does a raw memory copy, so if your data structures have pointer to themselves or to each other, the pointers in the copy will still point to the original objects.

In C++ you can also use `memcpy` if your array members are POD (that is, essentially types which you could also have used unchanged in C), but in general, `memcpy` will *not* be allowed. As others mentioned, the function to use is `std::copy`.

Having said that, in C++ you rarely should use raw arrays. Instead you should either use one of the standard containers (`std::vector` is the closest to a built-in array, and also I think the closest to Java arrays — closer than plain C++ arrays, indeed —, but `std::deque` or `std::list` may be more appropriate in some cases) or, if you use C++11, `std::array` which is very close to built-in arrays, but with value semantics like other C++ types. All the types I mentioned here can be copied by assignment or copy construction. Moreover, you can "cross-copy" from opne to another (and even from a built-in array) using iterator syntax.

This gives an overview of the possibilities (I assume all relevant headers have been included):

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  // This works in C and C++
  int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  int b[4];
  memcpy(b, a, 4*sizeof(int)); // int is a POD

  // This is the preferred method to copy raw arrays in C++ and works with all types that can be copied:
  std::copy(a, a+4, b);

  // In C++11, you can also use this:
  std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b));

  // use of vectors
  std::vector<int> va(a, a+4); // copies the content of a into the vector
  std::vector<int> vb = va;    // vb is a copy of va

  // this initialization is only valid in C++11:
  std::vector<int> vc { 5, 6, 7, 8 }; // note: no equal sign!

  // assign vc to vb (valid in all standardized versions of C++)
  vb = vc;

  //alternative assignment, works also if both container types are different
  vb.assign(vc.begin(), vc.end());

  std::vector<int> vd; // an *empty* vector

  // you also can use std::copy with vectors
  // Since vd is empty, we need a `back_inserter`, to create new elements:
  std::copy(va.begin(), va.end(), std::back_inserter(vd));

  // copy from array a to vector vd:
  // now vd already contains four elements, so this new copy doesn't need to
  // create elements, we just overwrite the existing ones.
  std::copy(a, a+4, vd.begin());

  // C++11 only: Define a `std::array`:
  std::array<int, 4> sa = { 9, 10, 11, 12 };

  // create a copy:
  std::array<int, 4> sb = sa;

  // assign the array:
  sb = sa;
}
```

Comment: why are you writing std all the time instead of just using the namespace of std ???

Comment: can't you do memcpy(b, a, sizeof a); too?

Comment: A Java array is more like `std:array` than like `std::vector`, because it has a fixed size.

Comment: Does `std::begin()` buy you anything in your second example of `std::copy`?

Comment: @wcochran: Yes: Should you ever decide to rewrite the code to use an actual container instead of a built-in array, you will not have to change that line. The less code you need to change, the less bugs you will introduce (and the less work you will have).

Answer (score 20):

Use `memcpy` in C, `std::copy` in C++.

Comment: For a small array I assume neither incur any function call overhead (`memcpy` should be a compiler intrinsic)?

Comment: @Mehrdad I didn't say otherwise; just making a comment. And I didn't downvote it, either.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `memcpy()`,

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

`memcpy()` copies the values of `num` bytes from the location pointed by `source` directly to the memory block pointed by `destination`.

If the `destination` and `source` overlap, then you can use `memmove()`.

```
void * memmove ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

`memmove()` copies the values of `num` bytes from the location pointed by `source` to the memory block pointed by `destination`. Copying takes place as if an intermediate buffer were used, allowing the destination and source to overlap.

Comment: Gonna have to -1 here.  The OP is specifically asking for a C++ solution and this answer says nothing of the situations in which `memcpy` is wrong, i.e., copying bytes is insufficient.

Comment: @EdS. In case you haven't noticed, the OP is now asking for a C *or* C++ solution.

Comment: When I answered the OP was asking for C/C++ solutions, though I personally believe "C/C++" is insult to both the languages. :)

Comment: fair enough, I didn't realize it was changing.  Maybe it even said that earlier and I missed it.  -1 removed.

Comment: @EdS. It always said "a function in C or C++".

Comment: @JimBalter: Like I said: "Maybe it even said that earlier and I missed it".  Of course, there is no one answer for two different languages.

Comment: @EdS "Like I said" ... yes, I know that. You speculated that it said it earlier; I asserted that it always said it ... no edit shows differently.

Answer (score 16):

I like the answer of Ed S., but this only works for fixed size arrays and not when the arrays are defined as pointers.

So, the C++ solution where the arrays are defined as pointers:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
...
const int bufferSize = 10;
char* origArray, newArray;
std::copy(origArray, origArray + bufferSize, newArray);
```

**Note**: No need to deduct `buffersize` with 1:

> 1. Copies all elements in the range [first, last) starting from first and proceeding to last - 1

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Comment: But how do we ensure that no "overlapping" will occur ?

Comment: I don't think you can, just don't use raw pointers ;-)

Answer (score 12):

In C you can use `memcpy`. In C++ use `std::copy` from the `<algorithm>` header.

Answer (score 6):

I give here 2 ways of coping array, for C and C++ language. [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) and [copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) both ar usable on C++ but **copy** is not usable for C, you have to use **memcpy** if you are trying to copy array in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for using copy (library function)
#include <string.h> // for using memcpy (library function)


int main(){

    int arr[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3};
    int brr[100];

    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr); // finding size of arr (array)

    std:: copy(arr, arr+len, brr); // which will work on C++ only (you have to use #include <algorithm>
    memcpy(brr, arr, len*(sizeof(int))); // which will work on both C and C++

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){ // Printing brr (array).
        std:: cout << brr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813). Don't ever use it. Instead of cplusplus.com, please use cppreference.com, which includes much better and up-to-date documentation of the standard. The `stdio.h` equivalent in C++ is `cstdio`, use that instead. Additionally, the code is fairly non-idiomatic C++. I think it'd be much clearer if you had showcased separate solutions for C and C++.

Answer (score 6):

Just include the standard library in your code.

```
#include<algorithm>
```

Array size will be denoted as `n`

Your old Array

```
int oldArray[n]={10,20,30,40,50};
```

Declare New Array in which you have to copy your old array value

```
int newArray[n];
```

Use this

```
copy_n(oldArray,n,newArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

in C++11 you may use `Copy()` that works for std containers

```
template <typename Container1, typename Container2>
auto Copy(Container1& c1, Container2& c2)
    -> decltype(c2.begin())
{
    auto it1 = std::begin(c1);
    auto it2 = std::begin(c2);

    while (it1 != std::end(c1)) {
        *it2++ = *it1++;
    }
    return it2;
}
```

Comment: It would be a better idea to pull the `std::end` out of the loop, for performance reasons (c1 doesn't change or invalidate iterators during the loop,so it's unnecessary to re-calculate the end).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, because you are switching to C++, **vector** is recommended to be used instead of traditional **array**. 
Besides, to copy an array or vector, `std::copy` is the best choice for you.

Visit this page to get how to use copy function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Example:

```
std::vector<int> source_vector;
source_vector.push_back(1);
source_vector.push_back(2);
source_vector.push_back(3);
std::vector<int> dest_vector(source_vector.size());
std::copy(source_vector.begin(), source_vector.end(), dest_vector.begin());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

1. Create an empty array.
2. Insert the elements.
3. Create a duplicate empty array of the same size.
4. Start for `i=0` to i=array length.
   5.  `newarray[i]=oldarray[i]`  (only for C++)

C++ program

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        int initA[100],finA[100],i,size;
        cout<<"Input the size of the array : ";
        cin>>size;
        cout<<"Input the elements of the first array";
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
               cin>>initA[i];
        }
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
             finA[i]=initA[i];
        }
        cout<<"The final array is\n";
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
               cout<<finA[i]<<" ";
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you would write a loop manually instead of just using the standard `copy` or `memcpy` methods.

Answer (score 1):

### C++ 20

You can use [`std::ranges::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/copy)

as simple, as `std::ranges::copy(a, b);`

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // ranges::copy, ranges::copy_if
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <iterator>  // ostream_iterator, begin, end
#include <numeric>   // iota

int main()
{
    float source[10];
    std::iota(std::begin(source), std::end(source), 0);

    float destination[10];

    std::ranges::copy(source, destination);

    std::cout << "destination contains: ";
    std::ranges::copy(destination, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "odd numbers in destination are: ";

    std::ranges::copy_if(destination, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "),
                         [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 1; });
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1a20680b445b5749

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting that while you can easily copy structs in C/C++, the same straightforward approach doesn't work for arrays. An amusing workaround involves casting an array to a struct pointer, making it possible to copy arrays, as demonstrated below:

```c
    int a[10] = {1, 2, 3};
    int b[10];

    {
        typedef struct {char _[sizeof(a)];} _;
        *(_*)b = *(_*)a;
    }
```

However, this solution may seem unattractive due to its unconventional appearance. To address this, we can encapsulate the operation within a macro:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_ASSIGN(x, y) \
{ assert(sizeof(x) == sizeof(y)); \
  typedef struct {char _[sizeof(x)];} _; *(_*)(x) = *(_*)(y);\
}


int
main(void)
{
    int a[10] = {1, 2, 3};
    int b[10];

    ARRAY_ASSIGN(b, a); // b = a

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]); ++i) {
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```