# C++ Copy an array created with new

Tags: c++, copy

I have created two arrays `List1` and `List2` with `new` in C++. `List1` is updated with data. I would like to copy `List1` to `List2`. I tried using

```
std::copy(std::begin(List1), std::end(List1), std::begin(List2));
```

However, this does not work and gives the following error message:

```
error: ‘begin’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

Any possible suggestions for this error? Or alternative ways to copy in C++?

Comment: @KerrekSB : Instead of new? I would not like to change this to std::vector, as the code is already under distribution.

Comment: `std::begin` is in `<iterator>`. They don't work on pointers, though.

Comment: @chris: already <iterator> is included

Comment: Do you use C++11? `std::begin` is from C++11.

Comment: @zch: yes, I use C++11

Comment: Is list2 big enough? Are you *sure* you want to copy the data?

Comment: What is it an array of?

Comment: @doctorlove: Both the lists are of same size

Comment: Maybe your compiler is missing support for this feature specifically, although I don't know of any that are off the top of my head.

Comment: You can use [std::array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16137997/1560509)

Comment: Don't use begin and end then, just give it the first and one beyond the last members. std::copy(&List1[0], &List1[whatever_size_you_newed], List2);

Comment: VS2012 gives different error messages, like `could not deduce template argument for '_Ty (&)[_Size]' from 'int *'`

Answer (score 2):

*"I have created two arrays List1 and List2 with **new** in C++*"

The `begin` and `end` free functions won't work on a pointer.

Even if everything is correct, you may end up with `no matching call to begin(T *&)`

`T` is the type of your pointer.

Use `std::vector` or `std::list` other STL container or just simply static arrays to work with `std::begin` and `std::end`

Comment: Is there an explanation? or they just didn't include its support

Comment: @POW: Would you recommend using memcpy?

Comment: @khajvah See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin), probably it answers your question

Comment: @SathishKrishnan that's why I asked what the arrays were. That will go wrong if the constructors need to do work

Comment: @P0W isn't that link saying std::begin *does* work on `a`, given `int a[] = { -5, 10, 15 };`?

Comment: @doctorlove yes I told for static array, it will work, see the answer. Also, here if a is passed in a function it won't, as arrays decays to pointer

Comment: @khajvah The explanation is simply that a pointer is a pointer, not an array. A pointer can point to the start of an array (e.g., allocated with `new[]`), but there is no portable way to tell if it does, or how big that array is. This means that implementing `end()` is essentially impossible, and it would seem pointless to provide `begin()` without `end()`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line towards the top of your cpp file:

```
#include <iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `std::begin` and `std::end` you need to include `<iterator>` and make sure your compiler supports C++11. However this won't fix your problem, as you cannot use them with pointers. Use `std::vector` instead.