# how to set a int array inside a struct in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have

```
struct board{
    int x[3];
    int y[3];
};

// in the class PatternReader
board PatternReader::testPattern1DX() {
   struct board aBoard;
   int x[3] = { 1,1,1 };
   aBoard = x;
   return aBoard;
}
```

Error is "incompatible types in assignment of `int *`".

How do you set arrays that are inside a struct?

Comment: You can't assign raw arrays. Use `std::array<int, 3>` instead.

Comment: Or if you can't use C++11 or Boost then `std::copy` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign arrays. However, you can can initialize the struct:

```
board PatternReader::testPattern1DX() 
{
   board aBoard = { 
       {1, 1, 1}, 
       {2, 2, 2} 
   };
   return aBoard;
}
```

This initializes `y` as well as `x`.

Comment: @TheOn It is valid code for C++ 2003 because board is an aggregate.

Comment: hmm..I should do research next time lol, thanks for correcting me, comment removed

Comment: Directly initializing the variable, rather than initializing a separate variable and then performing an assignment, is the right thing to do. However it is also a good idea to avoid raw arrays and to use `std::array` instead. This answer still works after replacing the raw arrays with `std::array`.

Answer (score 1):

Add an initializer function to the board struct:

```
struct board
{
   int x[3];
   int y[3];

   void initX(int* values)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         x[i] = values[i]
   }
};
```

Then use it:

```
board PatternReader::testPattern1DX() 
{
   struct board aBoard;
   int x[3] = { 1,1,1 };
   aBoard.initX(x);
   return aBoard;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
int x[3] = { 1,1,1 };
aBoard = x;
```

is creating a variable of type int* with the initial values 1,1,1.  You are then trying to assign that to a variable of type **board**.  You don't want to do that.  I think you intended:

```
int x[3] = { 1,1,1 };
aBoard.x = x;
```

Note the **.x** at the end of aBoard.  However, this is still wrong.  You can't assign arrays like that.  Look up "copying arrays" instead.  [Is there a function to copy an array in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137953/is-there-a-function-to-copy-an-array-in-c-c)

Honestly, I would suggest making board a class with constructors and and then you can make the constructors behave as you want, and also look into overloading assignment operators.  But for now, trying copying from x to aBoard.x is probably what you want.

Comment: "is creating a variable of type int*" No, arrays and pointers are not the same. The variable is in fact an array and its type is 'array of 3 ints'. If it were really a pointer then this would be legal: `int x[3] = {1,1,1}; x = nullptr;`

Comment: Thank you for making sure the technical stuff is accurate.  Yes, arrays and pointers are not exactly the same.  I used the term "int*" because in the code 
    `aBoard = x;`
it tries to assign aBoard to the int* from x, thus the error: "incompatible types in assignment of int *"