# Merging two arrays in a C++ program

Tags: c++, arrays, merge

I want to merge two arrays into one in a C++ program. For example:

```
int A[150],B[150];
int C[150][2];
```

And I want to have them as column vectors in C. For example in MATLAB I could use C=[A;B]. What is the easiest way?

Comment: It depends on if you want to copy them into the third array or if you want to have the third array hold references to the first two.

Comment: doing a basic loop which would took 2 sec to code ? and C++ is an Object Oriented language, so use object, for array you got the templated array in the standard library

Comment: the easiest way is this `std::vector<int> a; std::vector<int> b; std::vector<std::vector<int> > c; c.push_back(a); c.push_back(b);`

Comment: @tobi303 but this will hold the whole array on index 0, the whole array on index 1. IS this what he is asking for? maybe every element of both arrays on an index then need a for loop and push_back(s) for every array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a function to copy an array in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137953/is-there-a-function-to-copy-an-array-in-c-c)

Comment: @FirstStep i dont really understand, do you mean that he is asking for a `[150][2]` sized array, while I suggest dimensions `[2][150]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 150; ++i){
    c[i][0] = a[i];
    c[i][1] = b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.you can feel better comparing to another code.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[5]={3,2,1,4,5};
int  b[5]={9,8,6,7,0};
int c[10];    
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    cout<<"\n"<<a[i];

}

for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    cout<<"\n"<<b[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    c[i]=a[i];
}
for(int i=0,k=5;k<=10&&i<5;i++,k++)
{
    c[k]=b[i];
}
cout<<"merging";
for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
{
    cout<<"\n";
cout<<"\t"<<c[i];
}}
```