# how to pass array by value in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

i have the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *sort(int arr[]){
    for(int i =0; i< 1; i++){
        for(int j= 1; j< 5; j++){

            if(arr[i]< arr[j]){
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] =arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }

        }

    }
    for(int k=0; k<5;k++){
        cout<<arr[k];
    }
return arr;
}

int main(){  
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    sort(arr);
    for(int m=0; m<5; m++){
        cout<<arr[m];
    }
}
```

my  first problem is that  how to pass array by value  so that the original array does not change, and  secondly the my sort  function does not generate correct sorting i want  to sort array in decreasing order.

Comment: C++ inherits the C feature that arrays are not copyable, so they can't be passed by value.

Comment: use vector or c++ array instead

Comment: so we can't pass array by value

Comment: please see the sort  function it doesn't sort correctly out put of sort is 51234

Comment: That outer loop is pretty pointless. You *really* wanted `1` as the hard coded top limit of that ? I suspect not.

Answer (score 1):

In *idiomatic* C++, an array `arr` of 5 `int`s is declared `std::array<int, 5> arr;` or `std::vector<int> arr(5);`. Swapping of values is `std::swap`. Functions should either alter their parameters and return `void`, or alter a copy and return that value.

You also don't loop through every element in your outer loop.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void sort(std::array<int, 5> & arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < 5; j++){
            if(arr[i] < arr[j]){
                std::swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){  
    std::array<int, 5> arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    sort(arr);
    for(int m=0; m<5; m++){
        std::cout<<arr[m];
    }
}
```

However, the easiest way to sort is to use `<algorithm>`'s `std::sort`, which takes a range as two `Iterator` parameters

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main(){  
    std::array<int, 5> arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::greater<int>{});
    for(int m=0; m<5; m++){
        std::cout<<arr[m];
    }
}
```

Comment: or just `std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::greater<int>{});`, which will work for *either* a native `int arr[N]` array or a `std::array<int,N>`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't want OP to have any excuse to use `int arr[N]`. It doesn't belong in modern C++

Comment: i also have tried  the outer  loop through < arraysize but  it  does produce the  same result is the  one  above

Answer (score 0):

1) you can use c++ `swap` function instead using a temp variable

```
swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
```

2) your `for` loops should look like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(int j = i; j < 5; j++) {
```

The outer loop has to iterate through the whole array (from 0 to 4) and the inner has to iterate through the 'right side' of the array, because the left side is already sorted

> so we can't pass array by value

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16137997/6521788
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16137995/6521788

You can just copy the values into a new array

Comment: i  am preparing for a   university test for MS SE  admission where built in method  are  not allowed  to use  and also they told me  that if any question like sorting of array if it  is given then you need to  pass array by value.

Comment: @Hidayatullah Whoever "they" are in your statement, *"they told me that if any question like sorting of array if it is given then you need to pass array by value. "* doesn't know wtf "they" are talking about regarding how native arrays are passed as arguments in C++ (or C). Either they're naive, they're pranking you, or you misunderstood their statement.

Comment: @WhozCraig can we do  pass by value in java or c because  test is not restricted to c++

Comment: @Hidayatullah I already answered that question regarding both C and C++. For Java, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java).

Comment: @WhozCraig this is the statement from university."Your function should not alter the input parameter(s) in any way. For example, if your function needs to sort an array input parameter, you must sort a copy of the parameter, since otherwise, the caller of the function will see the sorted version of the input parameter.
For example,
 main()
{
  int [ ] a = new int [ ] {4, 2, 5};
  foo(a);
  // when program reaches here value of a will be {2, 4, 5} because an array is passed by reference!
}
void foo(int [ ] a)
{
  // sort the array a into ascending order
}

Comment: None of the questions require you sort any input parameter. If you choose to do so please sort a copy or you will receive no credit for the question."

Comment: @Hidayatullah Nowhere in that statement is the term "by value" ever even mentioned, so again, whomever said *that* to you didn't know what they were talking about.  In fact, in the text you provided, it specifically states expectations, telling you *precisely* what to do: *"you must sort a copy of the parameter"*. Granted, the verbiage in their instructions is dreadful, but at least they state what to do. If all else fails you could actually ask the instructors and/or TAs.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic answer:** you cannot pass arrays by value in C++.

**Solution 1:** Make a copy of your C-style array before passing it to your function, and remove your return statement as it won't be needed.

**Solution 2:** Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which is a container which provides the same functionality as a basic array, and as a copy constructor and copy assignment operators.

**Other remark**: 
The STL does provide sort algorithms ([`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)), so in your future programmer's life do not implement sorting algorithms yourself, unless you do something really specific where performance matters.

Comment: return statement is needed in my problem so i can't remove it

Answer (score 0):

your question indicates that there might be quite a bit of confusion as to how one deals with pointers in C++. If my assumption is incorrect then just skip ahead(i will provide "my solution"/correction at the end of this post).

To answer your first question: you can't pass C-style arrays per value in C++, nor by reference for that matter. Your only "option" would be looping through the pointer until '\n' is reached & store the contents in a new array created in your function.

which would be something along the lines of

```
'{
    int arrx[5] = {};

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        arrx[i] = arr[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) // print
    {
        std::cout << arrx[j];
    }
    return 0;
}`
```

A couple of other things about pointers:

```
int *sort(int arr[]){ -> arr[] passes a pointer to arr(same as *arr)
```

Pointer point to the first element in the memory pointed to & have no inherit size meaning

```
sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])
```

would not work inside your sort function(which could lead to problems if you dont know exactly how long the array you want to search is). a simple solution would be to pass the size of your array by value/reference to your function.
Another solution would be to loop through the array itself via something akin to

```
for(;arr != '\n'; arr++)
{
//your code here
```

You can get a lot more information about pointers than i could ever give you by visiting the various tutorial sites out there. 
for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

**But now back to your original question and hopefully an answer to it.**

```
int *sort(int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i< 1; i++) {
```

should be corrected to `for(int i=0; i< 5-1; i++)`

the sorting function you are trying to implement is called bubblesort. for further information & how exactly bubblesort works please refer to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubblesort

```
        for (int j = 1; j< 5; j++) {
```

should be corrected to `for(int i=0; i< 5-1-i; i++)` because the last elements are already in place.

```
        if (arr[i]< arr[j]) {
```

should be corrected to `if (arr[j]< arr[j+1])` because you want to compare(for example) the first element & the next element to get it in descending/ascending order. this gets done for every number pair in your array.

and finally:

```
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
```

should look something along the lines of:

```
        int temp = arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
```

please note that you can also reformat it to:

```
        int temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1] = temp; // same output
```

as an example: if arr[j] = 5 and arr[j+1] = 6 then you store the value j+1(6) in temp, overwrite arr[j+1] with j(5) and lastly store 6 at j to get descending order(hope i got that right now, but you get the gist)

lastly; as others have correctly pointed out already, you can use `std::swap` instead of using key/temp variables.