# Copying an array stored in one class to another class

Tags: c++

I have a situation where I need to copy an array of pointers stored in a class to another class.
Following the second answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137953/is-there-a-function-to-copy-an-array-in-c-c/16137995) question, I have created this reproducible example of what I am trying to do in my actual project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct A{};

class Something
{
public:
    static constexpr int nItems = 5;
    A* pA[nItems];
};

class AnotherThing
{
public:
    A* pACopy[Something::nItems];

    void CopyPointers(const A* pA[Something::nItems])
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(pA), std::end(pA), std::begin(pACopy));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Something something;
    AnotherThing anotherThing;
    anotherThing.CopyPointers(something.pA);
}
```

Error is in line `std::copy(std::begin(pA), std::end(pA), std::begin(pACopy));` and the error is
`no instance of overload function "std::begin" matches the argument list`. And its the same for `std::end` as well.

Comment: `#include <algorithm>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void CopyPointers(const A* pA[Something::nItems])` is equivalent to `void CopyPointers(const A** pA)`; `pA` is not an array but a pointer.

The fix is to use pointer arithmetic instead:

```
void CopyPointers(const A* pA[])
{
    std::copy(pA, pA + Something::nItems, std::begin(pACopy));
}
```