# Is there is a limit for a number of characters in wchar_t*

Tags: c++, wchar-t, wstring

I have a function that creates a copy of const char* in wchar_t*

```
wchar_t* to_wchar(const char* line)
{
    size_t line_length = strlen(line) + 1;
    wchar_t* wchar_name_temp = new wchar_t[line_length];
    size_t outSize;
    mbstowcs_s(&outSize, wchar_name_temp, line_length, line, strlen(line));
    wchar_t* wchar_name = wchar_name_temp;
    delete[] wchar_name_temp;
    return wchar_name;
}
```

But when I call it in the main function the problem that I get is that under a certain amount of symbols(44 for me), it assigns the address that was allocated on the heap in the 2nd line of the function despite creating a copy of that line in the stack

```
int main()
{
    wchar_t* str = to_wchar("10010101010101010101010101010101010101010101"); //random line
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `delete[] wchar_name_temp;` - you delete the buffer that you are about to return.

Comment: `wchar_t* wchar_name = wchar_name_temp;` does not create a copy of the string on the stack, it only copies pointers (memory addresses).

Comment: You should generally avoid pointers and manual allocations in C++ (via `new`/`malloc` or similar) and use the containers provided by the standard. You could pass a `std::string` to your function and create a `std::wstring` in it, set it via `std::mbstowcs()` (remember to resize the `std::wstring` first) and then return it.

Comment: `Is there is a limit for a number of characters in wchar_t*` -- A `wchar_t*` is just a pointer -- it is not a buffer.  Too many new C++ programmers confuse a pointer and what it points to.

Comment: Also, since you erroneously used `delete[]`, this suggests that any existing code using your function will now have an instant memory leak once you try to fix your mistake by not calling `delete[]`.  Out of the frying pan, and potentially into the fire.  The suggestion to always use `std::wstring` unless an API function calls for a `wchar_t*` (and at that point, you just use `c_str()`) is wise.

Answer (score 1):

> despite creating a copy of that line in the stack

You haven't made any copies. You've assigned a pointer. That's what your code says, and that's what it does.

```
wchar_t* wchar_name = wchar_name_temp;
delete[] wchar_name_temp;
return wchar_name;
```

This deletes allocated memory and then immediately returns it, which is almost certainly incorrect. If you want to copy a heap-allocated C-style array like this, you'll need to do so explicitly, using a `for` loop or [`std::copy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137953/is-there-a-function-to-copy-an-array-in-c-c).

But in this simple example, you should just return `wchar_name_temp` and forget about deleting at all, since you're returning it to the caller anyway.

Comment: I understand that but the question is the fact that if the line length is lower or equal to 44 symbols(for me) it works correctly but if it is higher it does not work

Comment: @Satoshic *the fact that if the line length is lower or equal to 44 symbols(for me) it works correctly* -- Sorry, but C++ does not work this way.  If you make mistakes such as what was pointed out in the answer, then it doesn't matter what experience you had with non-working code.  This is what *undefined behavior* is all about.   Ask yourself -- why would a magic number like `44` make a difference?  All you did was stumble on a magic value that seems to have worked, but someone else could have found 1 worked,  or 231 worked, or the program crashed right away regardless of the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
wchar_t* wchar_name_temp = new wchar_t[line_length];
// ...
wchar_t* wchar_name = wchar_name_temp;
delete[] wchar_name_temp;
return wchar_name;
```

First you allocate the wide string on the heap. `wchar_name_temp` points to the memory which is storing it. Then you copy only the location of that wide string into `wchar_name`. So both the pointers now point to the same memory and both live on the stack (no matter where they point). Only the wide string itself lives on the heap. When you then `delete[]` the memory (which still both pointers point to), it gets deleted for both of them and you return a dangling pointer. Using this pointer is UB (undefined behavior).

Generally speaking you should avoid any pointers and manual allocations/deallocations in C++ and rather use some containers from the standard library. Using them your function could look like this:

```
std::wstring to_wchar(const std::string& line) {
    std::wstring wstr(line.size(), L'\0');
    wstr.resize(std::mbstowcs(wstr.data(), line.data(), line.size()));
    return wstr;
}
```

Comment: I understand that but the question is the fact that if the line length is lower or equal 44 symbols(for me) it works correctly but if it is higher it is not working

Comment: @Satoshic this is undefined behaviour, anything may appear, even loking like working in some cases. Logic is wrong, program is wrong, correct it accordingly.