# how to initialize array return from a function in c

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to return array from a function and want to initialize in new array in main function.

My code isn't showing any error in codeblocks but its also not working.

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int * ReturnArray()
{
    static int *Arr;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        Arr[i] = i;
    }

    return Arr;
}

int  main()
{
    int *A,i;
    A = ReturnArray();

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",A[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What memory do you think you are writing to with this code? `Arr[i] = i;`

Comment: Arr is not an array

Comment: This is pure C and not C++, so why did you tag it C++?

Comment: @BoBTFish  sarcasm

Comment: A possible workaround for some pointer/array problems: [Why declare a struct that only contains an array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966570/why-declare-a-struct-that-only-contains-an-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not allocated any memory, so the Arr-Pointer in pointing nowhere.

What you probably want to do is

```
int * ReturnArray()
{
    int *Arr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        Arr[i] = i;
    }

    return Arr;
}
```

However, you need to `free()` that memory afterwards.